# Php mailer could not authenticate error all of a sudden with gmail

Tags: php, phpmailer

This code was working since an year but suddenly stopped working today. I didn't change gmail password or anything. Did gmail update something ?
How do I troubleshoot this ?

Error:
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

```
 require_once '../db/config.php';
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


function send_email($email, $code) {
    require_once '../ml/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
    require_once '../ml/PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
    require_once '../ml/PHPMailer/Exception.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
        $mail->isSMTP();                                         
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                   
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                
        $mail->Username   = 'example@gmail.com';            
        $mail->Password   = 'aaaabbbbb';                    
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;       
        $mail->Port       = 587;                                   

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('example@gmail.com', 'mycompany');
        $mail->addAddress($email); 
        $mail->addReplyTo('example@gmail.com', 'mycompany');


        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                      
        $mail->Subject = 'Verification code';
        $mail->Body    = 'Use the verification code to activate your account.<br> <span style="font-size: 20px;">'.$code.'</code>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'Use the verification code '.$code.' to activate your account';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Verification code has been sent to your email '.$email;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
}
```

Comment: It probably stopped working a week ago. Read this: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: is there alternatives. Does will outlook smtp work in its place ?

Comment: Did you read the article in full? It suggests 3 alternatives already.

Comment: Yes you could switch to another SMTP provider though, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the link @ADyson. I've updated [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps) with info about how to use gmail authentication.

Comment: outlook seems to work

Answer (score 9):

I recently implemented PHPMailer on my website with Gmail as the mail server etc. (had to replace swift mailer), so putting this here for anyone who needs this. For Gmail to work,

- First, go ahead and **log in** to the GMAIL account that you wish to use
  as the mail server.
- Once logged in, click this link which will take you to your accounts
  https://myaccount.google.com/
  Once that's loaded, on the left-hand side column, click on the    "**Security**" button.
- Once that page loads, you will see some boxes and one of them will
  say "Signing in to google". In it, you should see some options with
  one of them being "App Passwords". Should look something like
  this

(*Yellow highlight below is the button you need*):

[image]

**Please note:** if you don't see it(yellow highlighted "app password" button, then this means that you have to **enable 2-Step verification first**.

- Assuming you have 2FA enabled, click on the "**app passwords**" button and
  sign in again.
- On the next screen, simply hit the "**Select App**" dropdown button and
  then select "Other (Custom Name)". Give it a name and click
  "generate".
- This will bring up a popup with a long password on it. Make sure to save the password temporarily while you work on your app because once you close out of that popup, you cant view the password again. If you lose it, you'll have to create another one.

From here, all you have to do is go to your code and **replace your regular GMAIL email password, with your newly generated app password**.

Make sure to have the host address as "smtp.gmail.com"

the port is 465

and the encryption type as SMTP or
"`$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;`"

And that's it. You should be good to go. Good luck and happy coding

Comment: This solution works for me! Thank you very much @somdow for saving valuable time for all of us.

Answer (score 1):

Google stopped less secure app support for non Google Business suite users from 30 May 2022.

You can use any other email service providers. If you have your own domain with email hosting, you can use one email account as smtp.

Comment: True...but a good answer would actually offer a solution rather than merely stating the problem.

Comment: You can use any other email service providers. If you have your own domain with email hosting, you can use one email account as smtp. 

There are 3rd party smtp service providers available.

Comment: That's one option, yes. But if OP wants to stay with gmail there also options available...(see the comments under the question)

Answer (score 1):

Turn on two factor authentication then generate app password

1. Go to your Google Account.
2. Select Security.
3. Under "Signing in to Google," select 2-Step Verification. At the
   bottom of the page, select App passwords. Enter a name that helps
   you remember where you’ll use the app password. Select Generate.
4. To enter the app password, follow the instructions on your screen.
   The app password is the 16-character code that generates on your
   device. Select Done.

then use this code

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; // Specify the SMTP server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'senderemailaddress@gmail.com'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'app_password_without_space'; // SMTP password
$mail->Port = 465; 

$mail->setFrom('sender_email@gmail.com', 'Sender name'); // Sender's email and name

$mail->addAddress('receiver_email@gmail.com', 'Receiver name'); // Recipient's email and name
//$mail->addReplyTo('sender@example.com', 'Sender Name'); // Reply-to email and name (optional)
//$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'My Subject';
$mail->Body = 'Hello, this is a test email.';
$mail->AltBody = 'Hello, this is a plain text version of the email.';

if ($mail->send()) {
    echo 'Email sent successfully!';
} else {
    echo 'Email sending failed: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```